# I am using a sub-process to call a python script and when it runs it gives me this error. I have already installed all the libraries using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "skip_ads.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ImportError: No module named pyautogui
```

I have already installed the pyautogui library but still, it says No module named pyautogui,
and I am using a subprocess to call this python script, if I use the normal command line to run this script it runs normally but when I use subprocess it does not run.

Comment: The likely issue is that you have multiple installations of Python.  Try doing `python -V` in your subprocess and see if the answer is the same as what you get on the command line.

Comment: You may also need to check the PATH (python, library paths etc...) used by your subprocess

Comment: Why do you want to execute a python script from another using subprocess? You should create a module instead of a script and try to import/use that module in your calling python program.

Comment: the answer was to do sudo pip3 install pyautogui

Answer (score 0):

When calling subprocess, use a variable to point out to the same python.exe you use for your skip_ads.py file.

```
Python = r'C:\Users\'your user'\PycharmProjects\venv\Scripts\python.exe'

subprocess.call([(Python), skip_ads.py ])
```